# Updating a ListFragment based on Async Task result

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

**Scenario :**
I am having a list fragment which displays a list of friends. When an list item is pressed, I'm showing the details of the friend in a dialog fragment.

**Problem:**
In the dialog fragment, I'm having an option to delete the friend from my friend list (in a remote server) . I'm using Async tack to perform this. After returning from the dialog fragment, how should I update the 'old' friend list. **How do I trigger a fragment 'reload'.** Since the async task is not aware of the custom list adapter being used in the list fragment.

Sorry, I will add the code ASAP. If anyone have met this scenario before kindly provide your suggestions.

**Edit:** After successfully deleting a friend from the friend list in a remote server, I want to reload the list being displayed in the list fragment. Is there a way to trigger the dataSetChanged notification in the list fragment itself.

Comment: One best & Performance wise solution is use Interface implemented in ListFragment & create in DialogFragment. you can handle Listfragment Friend List Add/update/Delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem. I'm guessing the `ListFragment` is reading from some data source - be it an `ArrayAdapter` or a `SimpleCursorAdapter` (or something similar) - and your task is also modifying that source. When the `AsyncTask` finishes, you should just be able to get that fragment and update the underlying data. For example:

```
// ...
void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    ListFragment lFrag = (ListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.yourListFragment);
    BaseAdapter adapter = (BaseAdapter) lFrag.getListAdapter();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: How Could you call getFragmentManager() from AsyncTask Class??!

Comment: I don't remember at this point, but you could have a `WeakReference` to a `FragmentActivity`, which would let you call `getFragmentManager()`.

Answer (score 1):

So you will be populating the ListView with an ArrayList.

- Delete the Item from the ArrayList with index = ListViewItemIndex
  clicked.
- call notifyDataSetChanged on the Adapter you are using.